# combining two animated GIF icons

Tags: linux, icons, gif

I'm trying to combine two GIF icons and I would like the result to be like what I see when I open a document in libreoffice draw or libreoffice impress , import these 2 icons and group them : both are animated at the same time . The problem is that if I export the group the animation is lost .

I used Gimp and I was able to combine those 2 icons and export the group without loosing the animation but they were no more animated at the same time : GIF1 was animated , then GIF2 then GIF1 and so on .

question : what should I do or what program should I use to get (GIF1 + GIF2) animated as a group = as if they were a single icon ? Frame rates are 14 and 17 .

I'm on Debian 11

Comment: See the free online tool [Combine 2 GIF images side by side](https://ezgif.com/combine). After the merged GIF is created, it can be modified by other tools, perhaps by GIMP. Does this answer the question?

Comment: "PhotoScape" is a free Windows tool what can combine GIFs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asks for software recommendations. See: https://meta.superuser.com/a/5373/705502

Comment: @harrymc it worked but the frequency of one of the icons changed radically, but thanks to the tools offered by the site I was able to obtain an acceptable result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poster was able to fix his problem using the free online tool
[Combine 2 GIF images side by side](https://ezgif.com/combine).

The merged GIF was not perfect, but this was fixed by the other tools
offered by the site.